# Is this a mistake in this integral calculation

Tags: complex-analysis

> Please can someone tell me if the first step in this solution ([notes available here](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~cwalkden/complex-analysis/complex_analysis.pdf)) is a mistake?

I believe that if $\gamma: [a,b]\to \mathbb C$ is a path from $\gamma(a)$ to $\gamma (b)$ then $-\gamma$ is a path from $\gamma (b)$ to $\gamma (a)$ and hence the first equality would be:

$$ \int_{-\gamma} f = \int_b^a f(-\gamma)(-\gamma')$$

Here is the original solution:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$-\gamma$ is a function made such that when $t = a$,  $-\gamma(a) =  \gamma(b)$ and  when $t = b$,  $-\gamma(b) =  \gamma(a)$. So in the first step the bounds are still from $a$ to $b$. In your reasoning you jump directly to the third line.

For the step from the first line to the second line, notice that the derivative of $-\gamma(t)$ is :

$$ -\gamma'(t) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(\gamma(a+b-t)) = \frac{\mathrm{d}\gamma}{\mathrm{d}t}(a+b-t) \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}(a+b-t)}{\mathrm{d}t} = - \frac{\mathrm{d}\gamma}{\mathrm{d}t}(a+b-t)$$

Comment: Ok, right. But how does he get from the first line to the second line? There it seems that a minus magically appears.

Comment: @learner Read the lines before the calculation *carefully*